# jQM 1.4.2 Collapsible set not refreshing properly after dynamic content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I know this question has been asked before and I've read all the solutions. None of them work.

I have a collapsible set with 5 collapsible elements in it.

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" id="mySet" data-inset="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="1">
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="2">
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="3" >
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="4">
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" id="5">
  </div>
</div>
```

The components are built with jQuery and each one has its html updated with.

```
$('#' + key).html(myHTMLString);
```

Where the key is the id of the div and the myHTMLString is constructed in jQuery.

This works perfectly the first time you go to the page but after that the collapsible set loses all formating. There are no anchors around the collapsible headings and no div with a class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit" as you get on the first time you visit.

I've tried every combination of

```
$('#mySet').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
$("#mySet").collapsibleset("refresh");
$( "#mySet" ).trigger( "updatelayout" );
$("#mySet").enhanceWithin();
```

and more that I can find. Nothing changes it.

Any ideas why? I'd be far less baffled if it didn't work at all but being fine on the first visit but not the next? Bizarre.

EDIT:

I've altered the code so the h4 and p tags are in the html document instead of being dynamically inserted, and I'm adding the data to them like this:

```
 $('#' + key + "_head").html(myHeadingHTMLString);
 $('#' + key + "_content").html(myContentHTMLString);
```

This has restored the collapsible div but it has still taken away the formatting, because on the second visit (it still works fine the first time) the anchor tag with

```
<a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus ui-btn-inherit">
```

is not added on the second visit.

Why on Earth not? I'm using .collapsibleset() at the end of constructing it all and its the same whatever I do.

Comment: `.collapsibleset();` is enough.

Comment: I've tried that (and just tested it again). It doesn't work. It works the first time (as always) but not after that.

Comment: when are you loading dynamic elements?

Comment: When the page loads. You click the link to the page, which is a normal anchor. It has a bound click handler that then builds the page. When we were building the entire page it was fine, but now we are trying to leave as much static code in the html page as we can. Previously we built the entire collapsible including all the divs. But we shouldn't need to do that - we're trying to just manipulate the content of the divs, for performance sake.

Comment: does `click` event fire on second click? are you wrapping code in `pagecreate` of that specific page?

Comment: I'm not using pagecreate but the code definitely executes - the data is pulled from the right places and the page is almost properly built; its just that anchor that is automatically added in the collapsible that is not added the second time you go to the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51607/discussion-between-omar-and-subjective-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#mySet").enhanceWithin().collapsibleset('refresh');
```